# MissingPluginException when adding flutter_facebook_login in Flutter

Tags: flutter

When I add **flutter_facebook_login** in **pubspec.yaml** then one or more plugins don't work, especially **shared_preferences**. When I remove **flutter_facebook_login** then all plugins work fine.

Comment: I saw at plugin repo, others have also mentioned, and they all have missed some points while including this login plugin in there project, please look at the repo and check if you have followed all steps or you should look into those already created issue at github.

Comment: kindly send me any reference link

Comment: you can Follow these two :) https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/issues/277  and   https://github.com/roughike/flutter_facebook_login/issues/262

Comment: Please specify what you mean about it not working. What's the error?